# cakephp ->set() a value in an object

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I can use the cakephp set() to add a value in an object at the top level but I also need to set a value for an object inside the object and I can seem to access it. Is this possible?

I need to add business_id inside the employee object.

I though I might use `$user->set->employee('business_id', '1');` but I get an error on the employee part.

```
object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

'email' => 'dfgdfg@sdfsdf.com',
'new_password' => 'ttt',
'confirm_password' => 'ttt',
'employee' => object(App\Model\Entity\Employee) {

    'name' => 'dsfsfsdfsfd',
    'email' => 'sdfsdfsdf@sdfsdf.com',
    'surname' => 'sdfsdfsdfsdf',
    'employee_num' => 'sdfsdfsdfsd',
    '[new]' => true,
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

I tried it a couple of different ways and I got it work by `$user->employee->set('business_id', '1');`

Comment: So you are savior? Hail!